# Mouse busy cursor does not work with wine

Tags: wine, mouse, cursor

When starting any program on Ubuntu 18.04 the mouse cursor transforms to an animated wheel to indacate that something is going on that we have to work for. But this does not work with wine. When starting wine the cursor keeps beeing a pointer. Especially in that situation it would be a very useful information when wine and the with wine started program is ready to use.

Is there any way to activate the mouse busy cursor for wine?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that adding "StartupNotify=true" to the desktop shortcut file the Mouse busy cursor sometimes works. Please follow the link for more details.

https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/startup-notification.html.en